# Make a single button active in a group of buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am working on a directive that displays many buttons. 
I would like to call onclick method only on active button, and not on inactive buttons.

```
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-click="activeButton()">All</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}">Small<span class="price">  $241+</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" click="activeButton()">Medium<span class="price">  $241+</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" click="activeButton()">Large<span class="price">  $241+</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" click="activeButton()">SUV<span class="price">  $241+</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" click="activeButton()">VAN<span class="price">  $241+</span></button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" click="activeButton()">More</button>
</div>

app.controller('appCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.isActive = false;
    $scope.activeButton = function() {
    $scope.isActive = !$scope.isActive;
  }  
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: When do you want to make the button active. I mean `onclick / onhover`?

Comment: You can make buttons disabled, e.g: `  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-class="{'active': isActive}" ng-disabled="isActive" ng-click="activeButton()">All</button>
`

Comment: Javascript Lover - SKT, Yeah.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have this html:

```
<div class="container">
    <button ng-repeat="item in buttons" type="button" class="btn" ng-class="item.isActive"
            ng-click="activeButton(item)">{{item.name}}<span class="price">  {{item.price}}</span></button>            

</div>
```

Then you can have this in your controller:

```
$scope.buttons = [{
    name: "All",
    price: "",
    isActive: "inactive"
  }, {
    name: "Small",
    price: "$230+",
    isActive: "inactive"
  }, {
    name: "Medium",
    price: "$235+",
    isActive: "inactive"
  }, {
    name: "Large",
    price: "$237+",
    isActive: "inactive"
  }, {
    name: "SUV",
    price: "$240+",
    isActive: "inactive"
  }, {
    name: "VAN",
    price: "$241+",
    isActive: "inactive"
  }, {
    name: "More",
    price: "",
    isActive: "inactive"
  }];
  $scope.activeButton = function(item) {
      angular.forEach($scope.buttons, function(button, index) {
        if (item.name == button.name) {
          button.isActive = "active";
        } else {
          button.isActive = "inactive";
        }
      });
  }
```

And in your css it would be smth like:

```
.active {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inactive {
   background-color: white;
}
```

Check [this plunkr](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/wJHCqZVyxDE48eiL).

Comment: @mplungjan the code is here, no need to go unless you want to see all the details.